# What do the different MS Access Table_Types mean?

Tags: ms-access, powershell

I am querying a .mdb file with PowerShell and the Microsoft Access Engine. Some tables appear to be local while other appear to be remote. In fact I have seen five different TABLE_TYPES.

- LINK
- PASS_THROUGH
- TABLE
- VIEW
- ACCESS TABLE

What does each mean? How does each limit my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - LINK. "The Table is a linked table from a non-ODBC data source."
> - PASS_THROUGH. "The Table is a linked table from an ODBC data source."
> - TABLE. "The Table is a table."
> - VIEW. "The Table is a row-returning, non-parameterized query."
> - ACCESS TABLE. "The Table is a Microsoft Access system table."
>
> From http://www.mvp-access.es/buho/ficheros/nombrestablasmdb.txt